# Retrieving Data from SQL Server using python and pyodbc through Model

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I'm using Python and pyodbc to extract data from my SQL Server, put it into a list and then print that list. It works fine when I enter everything manually. But I'm trying to use models to clean up the code and ultimately make everything very user friendly.

This is my `Main` file:

```py
import Models

cursor = Models.dbConnect()
states = Models.dbSelect(cursor, "State")

print(states)
```

and this is my `Models` file

```py
import pyodbc


def dbConnect(driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", server="serverName", database="dbName"):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={" + driver + "};"
                    "Server=" + server + ";"
                    "Database=" + database + ";"
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    return cursor

def dbSelect(cursor, Column="*", Table="States", Rest=""):
    cursor.execute('SELECT ' + Column + ' FROM ' + Table + ' ' + Rest)
    results = []
    for row in cursor:
        results.append(row)
    return results
```

This return the following messy result

```
[('Alabama', ), ('Alaska', ), ('Arizona', ), etc]
```

I can easily clean this up by manually entering the specific column I'm trying to call as such

```py
for row in cursor:
    results.append(row.State)
```

which returns the following results

```
 ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', etc]
```

When I just use 'Column' instead it crashes because row object doesn't have a column attribute.

```py
for row in cursor:
    results.append(row.Column)
```

I want to only have to have to enter the wanted column in the `Main` file, but everything I've tried either forced me to manually enter the wanted column in both my `Main` and `Models` files, or work with messy result.

Comment: Just to clear up, are you asking to use `row.Column` where `Column` is a variable?

Comment: @EcSync. Well, the correct Variable is 'inside' of Column. In my example ```Column == "State" ```. But that's not how Column is treated. Column is treated as just 'Column' not "State". The two solutions which I could come up with are: 1. forcing python to somehow treat Column as State which I can't figure out (Don't even know if that's possible) or 2. There might be some way to make this work that I don't know about using pyodbc